# How to use non-latin characters with ScriptSharp

Tags: character, script#, non-latin

I am trying to write:

```
options.Title = "Русский текст";
```

and in compiled JS i am getting:

```
options.title = '\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd';
```

So all characters in the title are replaced with '\ufffd'. And i am getting "??????? ?????" instead of "Русский текст" into markup.

Comment: Can you also add what is the expected script that would make it work? What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving your source file (.cs) with another encoding like UTF-8 with signature (Codepage 65001). You can find this option under File -> Advanced Save Options in Visual Studio. This works for me with Turkish characters. Seems like ScriptSharp doesn't play well with single byte encodings.